# Flume - Could not configure sink - No channel configured for sink

Tags: hadoop, flume-ng

I have configured flume to read logs file and write to HDFS. When I start the flume the log files are read but it not written to HDFS. `flume.log` has the warning message - `could not configure sink - no channel configured for sink` but I already assigned a channel to sink in the conf-file.

Given below is the conf-file and error message:

```
File: spool-to-hdfs.properties
# List all components.
agent1.sources = source1
agent1.sinks = sink1
agent1.channels = channel1

# Describe source.
agent1.sources.source1.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.source1.spoolDir =/Suriya/flume/input_files

# Describe channel
#agent1.channels.channel1.type = file
#agent1.channels.channel1.checkpointDir = /Suriya/flume/checkpointDir
#agent1.channels.channel1.dataDirs =/Suriya/flume/dataDirs
agent1.channels.channel1.type = memory

# Describe sink
agent1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
#agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/hdfs/Suriya/flume
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost/hdfs/Suriya/flume
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType= DataStream
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

# Bind source and sink to channel
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channels = channel1

**-- starting the agent**
flume-ng agent --conf-file spool-to-hdfs.properties --conf /etc/flume/conf --name agent1;
```

**flume.log**

```
03 Aug 2015 23:37:16,699 WARN  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSinks:697)  - Could not configure sink  sink1 due to: No channel configured for sink: sink1
org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: No channel configured for sink: sink1 at org.apache.flume.conf.sink.SinkConfiguration.configure(SinkConfiguration.java:51)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Replace the bind part with.

# Bind source and sink to channel
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channels = channel1

This bind config
# Bind source and sink to channel
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1


agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1 
Looks okay

BUT
agent1.sinks.sink1.channels = channel1
Should be 
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

Let us know how it goes.